# fancybox iframe width on iPhone displays wider than screen

Tags: iphone, iframe, fancybox

On iPhone I am having problems getting the fancybox (2.1.5) popup to size the html contents within the screen width (so that the user doesnt have to horizontally scroll over).

I am using the iframe fancybox method to display the page contents when the user clicks on an `<a>` tag thumbnail. This action calls up a fancybox (using type:iframe) to display a new page with an HTML5 video in it. The problem is that the iframe is wider than the screen, and the page content (including the video) partially displays off the screen, requiring the user to scroll horizontally to the right in order to see the whole page. It seems like fancybox is using the iPhone's reported innerWidth value instead of the clientWidth value. Note I have included the following in the head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

I also tried including the `overlay : {locked : true }` method which doesnt help this particular issue

You can see the problem at http://notheremedia.com  Click on the first "Cricket Lives" thumbnail using an iPhone.

Any assistance here is most appreciated.

Fancybox init script below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Fancybox setup call 
    $(".iframe").fancybox({
        width       : '667px',
        openEffect  : 'elastic', 
        openSpeed   : 1000,
        closeEffect : 'elastic', 
        closeSpeed  : 500,
        type        : 'iframe',
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                locked : true 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: could you post your full jQuery fancybox initialization script? (you shouldn't ask people to click on unknown links.... rather create a fiddle to reproduce the issue ;)

Comment: Does it occur the same if you open the iframed page directly (not in fancybox) on mobile?

Comment: Apologies for the delay! My problem is that I dont have an iPhone so I'm stealing time on another's. It works fine going directly to the page link, in other words the page contents fit within the screen width, and no horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. It is not a problem with Fancybox. The cause was due to my using `width:inherit` on a textarea control on the page. When I changed to using `width:100%`, the FB iframe now sizes properly within the screen width. Apologies for the false alarm.